# group policy deployed printers - print management - (redirected 1) issue?

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, group-policy, network-printer, shared-printers

im having an issue with group policy deployed printers..

i have a/d OUs for each category of computers..

example:

top OU: Computers

- dtsc 5 computers - deploys dtsc printers with group policy
- lvm 5 computers - deploys lvm printers with group policy
- nm: 5 computers - deploays nm printers with group policy

top OU: Users

- dtsc 5 users - no group policies
- lvm 5 users  - no group policies
- nm 5 users   - no group polices

i setup GPs under each computer OU for printer deployment, sharing them on a central server. no GPs are set under the user OUs everything is computer based, and the properties are set in the computer policies.

the GPs work to an extent - the printers show up, but so does all the other ones.. for example, i have a policy in dtsc that deploys the dtsc printers from the server. but dtsc can also see the lvm and nm printers even though the lvm and nm polocies are not linked under the dtsc ou? each printer has (redirect 1) listed at the end of it as well

anyone have any idea why this may be?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would start by running `gpresult` from the cmd of a computer getting all the printers.  Look in the computer settings section to see if the other printer policies are being applied to that machine.

Is this in a Terminal Services environment? The "redirected 1" next to the printers seems to suggest that.

Check your policies to see if any settings under

```
Computer Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\
Terminal Services\Terminal Server\Printer Redirection
```

are set

If they are not try setting `Do not allow client printer redirection` to enabled on one of the printer policies and see if the printers with (redirected #) go away.

Since only one policy is being applied, I would then try removing the policy, and removing the printers.  Then see if they re-appear without the policy in place.

Comment: @Cheekaleak the systems used to be terminal services about 5 years ago. now they are not. i checked the default domain policy and all of the printer policies none of them have anything in the printer redirection folder. im going to check a few other policies that where already on the system (dc controllers etc policies) to be sure, but i dont think. I just created the printer policies today - there are 5 printer policies in total and each one shows up for every ou with the redirection label in ( ) s bellow it

Comment: Could you take a screen shot of where the ()'s are appearing?  Are they showing up next to the printers themselves or next to the printer GPOs?

Comment: @Cheekaleak i added the image to original post - it is next to the pritners. these ones say redirected 2..

Comment: @Cheekaleak the ones that are supposed to be listed on this machine are the ones with [CORP] and [LVM] tagged in the name

Comment: @Jeff Try enabling the Printer Redirection setting I added to the answer.  It looks like you are getting unwanted redirected printers but still getting the correct printers from the policy.  Enabling that setting should remove the unwanted printers.

Comment: @Cheekaleak it seems to have worked on that machine - i am going to bounce around to other remote machines and see if the issue is resolved on those as well , i'll let you know and mark as solved as soon as i check a few. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could create security groups for the computer groups, then add the computer accounts to each of the computer groups. Then set the Security Filtering of the group policy to add the printers to only apply the printer GPO to the group you want it to and remove Authenticated Users.

After looking at your screen shot, you might check this link out

http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2007/08/24/terminal-server-and-printer-redirection.aspx